# convert function based view to class based view django

Tags: python, django

I am tried to do get form data by POST method in a variable and then try to validate it. I have done it with django function based view. But now I want to convert it into django class based vied. So can any one help to convert my following code to django class based view.

```
from .forms import contact_form
def contact_us(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = contact_form(request.POST)
        # return HttpResponse(form)
        if form.is_valid():
            return HttpResponse("Data is valid")
        else:
            return HttpResponse("Data is invalid")
```

my idea is basically like as below:
'''

```
from django.views.generic.edit import FormView
from .forms import ContactForm

class ContactUsView(FormView):
    def post(self , request):
        # this method will handle event when reques is come through POST method

    def get(delf , request):
            # this method will handle event when reques is come through POST method
```

'''

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [**`FormView`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.FormView):

```
from django.views.generic.edit import FormView
from .forms import contact_form

class ContactUsView(FormView):
    form_class = contact_form
    template_name = 'name-of-template.html'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        return HttpResponse('Data is valid')

    def form_invalid(self, form):
        return HttpResponse('Data is invalid')
```

For a GET request, the default behavior will be to render the `template_name` with as `form` variable the form object of the specified `form_class`.

---

> **Note**: Forms in Django are written in *PascalCase*, not *snake_case*,
> so you might want to rename the model from <s>`contact_form`</s> to `ContactForm`.

Comment: actually i want to create system like that single method will handle rendering of form page(request will comde through GET method) and validation of form(request will come through POST method). My idea i shown in question(i edited my question). Is it possible to do. If yes then please can you give me demo.

Comment: sorry for delay. Now i updated my code.

Comment: @smitpatel: for that you can use a simple `View`, but that is not the aim of a CBV: the aim is to abstract away logic that is very common: here the view will automatically create a form object, check if it is valid, and call `form_valid` or `form_invalid` if the form is valid.